# Why are some backups grey and others purple in Time Machine in Lion?

Tags: time-machine

I started Time Machine for the first time in Lion (you know, to make sure everything was working properly), and I noticed something odd – on the timeline on the right side of the screen, some backups were purple and others were grey. There wasn't an apparent difference between the purples and greys to me, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

[image: Go go vertical image!]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just recently noticed this, too, and discovered this Apple KB article: [OS X Lion: About Time Machine's "local snapshots" on portable Macs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4878)

> When you enter the Time Machine browser (used to restore data), local
>   snapshots will appear on the timeline along with regular backups
>   distinguished by different colors. **Gray tick marks represent local
>   snapshots and pink tick marks represent backups stored on your
>   external backup disk or Time Capsule.** Note: Pink tick marks will be
>   dimmed if your portable computer is not connected to your external
>   backup disk or Time Capsule.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: I had no idea Time Machine stored local backups as well. I guess you *do* learn something new everyday. :)

Comment: @KevinY The local backups is new in Loin. It's handy if you have a MacBook Pro since it keeps backing up locally while offline, and once it sees your backup device, does a delta update. It has improved backup speed in my house by almost 100%.